# Write Locks in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I read somewhere that `MongoDB` holds db level write lock, does this mean that when someone updates any `collection` others are not allowed to read other `collection` or how it works. Also when someone writes anything to the db how `MongoDB` acquires write lock and what is its granularity?

Answer (score 7):

Your interpretation matches the "How granular are locks in MongoDB?" part in [MongoDB FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#how-granular-are-locks-in-mongodb):

> **How granular are locks in MongoDB?**
>
> Beginning with version 2.2, MongoDB implements locks on a per-database
>   basis for most read and write operations. Some global operations,
>   typically short lived operations involving multiple databases, still
>   require a global “instance” wide lock. Before 2.2, there is only one
>   “global” lock per mongod instance.
>
> For example, if you have six databases and one takes a write lock, the
>   other five are still available for read and write.

As for the way the locking works:

> **What type of locking does MongoDB use?**
>
> MongoDB uses a readers-writer 
>   *[ed: also known as “multi-reader” or “shared exclusive”]* lock that allows concurrent 
>   reads access to a database but gives exclusive access to a single write
>   operation.
>
> When a read lock exists, many read operations may use this lock.
>   However, when a write lock exists, a single write operation holds the
>   lock exclusively, and no other read or write operations may share the
>   lock.
>
> Locks are “writer greedy,” which means writes have preference over
>   reads. When both a read and write are waiting for a lock, MongoDB
>   grants the lock to the write.

Comment: how it is going to behave in sharded environment?

Comment: The MongoDB FAW I linked in my answer has also the answer for that question :) (shortly, the instances are independent in this regard)

Answer (score 4):

The lock *scope* has been moving in the various MongoDB versions. They're getting closer to the data over time.

- Versions before 2.2 had a global lock per MongoDB instance.

  - A lock held on one database on the instance blocked writes to **all** databases on that instance.
- As of v2.2, this was changed to be a database lock.

  - A lock on one collection would block writes to the entire database.
- Collection level locks are on the future feature list but are not yet on the road-map ([the JIRA ticket that's tracking this feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240)).

Mongo is pretty good about lock yielding. The impact of replicating and sharding on the behavior of locks is important if you are building a system that uses those, as the options you choose to implement can affect how much blocking locks affect your system.

Comment: how it is going to behave in sharded environment?

Comment: @PhalguniMukherjee Simple sharding (no replication) has the lock apply separately to each node's database. Sharding is a way to get around excessive lock-percentages.

Comment: Currently as of 3.0 version , we have document level locking.

Answer (score 3):

From MongoDB version 3.0, locks are available at following granularity levels :

1. Global (MongoD instance) – All databases in it are affected by the lock.
2. Database – Only the Database on which lock is applied is affected.
3. Collection – Only the Collection on which lock is applied is affected.
4. Document – Only the Document on which lock is applied is affected.

Locks for Global, Database and Collection are handled by MongoDB while Document level locking is left to Storage Engine.

References :

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use
2. [MongoDB Tutorial](https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-tutorial/) - [MongoDB Locks](https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongodb-locks/)